# How to solve this ODE (equation of curve passes from a point)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been asked a question as follow;

$dy-(\sin(x+y)+\cos(x+y))dx=0$ is the equation which supports the equation of a curve that passes through point $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$

Question asks that, find the equation of the curve. I just wrote the equation in proper way and took the integral of both sides. Was that right? Or what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can proceed like this:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(x+y)+\cos(x+y)\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin y+ \cos y) \Rightarrow \\ \frac{dy}{(\sin y+ \cos y)}=\frac{dx}{(\sin x+\cos x)}\\ \Rightarrow \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt2(\cos y+\frac{\pi}{4})}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt2(\cos x+\frac{\pi}{4})}$$
now we must integrate and substitute the point given to find the answer.
$$\tanh^{-1}(\frac{\tan(\frac{y}{2})+1}{\sqrt 2})=\tanh^{-1}(\frac{\tan(\frac{x}{2})+1}{\sqrt 2})+C$$
then by substituting $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$ we get an imaginary solution for $C$ !

Comment: Ohh thanks, this is my stupidity. It is easy as possible.